# HomeScreen Display Reference

Tags: android, homescreen

complete noob to android. Trying to make an app in which I am trying to use the **presentation class** to display the home screen on the secondary display .... in short I'm trying to make the secondary display the primary display... I've tried a few hack such as making an overlay screen but it somehow doesn't work ... is there any way to get reference to the **display object of the home screen**....so i can use that to display it on the secondary display... **please help guys** :D.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to get reference to the display object of the home screen

No. That is not your app.

The exception would be if you write your own home screen and integrate it into this `Presentation` app.

You are welcome to use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+ to take screenshots of the primary display, to show in your `Presentation`. However, all that will do is accomplish the same display mirroring that is part of standard Android (and be slower as well).

Comment: hmmm... That is the app, I think i'm not explaining it correctly. Ok so the app is a presentation service, but has a base activity which holds the reference to the service and can start and stop it. The app in functionality is similar to 'vysor' it displays the home screen on the secondary display and converts the primary device into a touch pad ... So i need to literally display the android home screen on the secondary device .... like you suggested media projection but that would be so slow....

Comment: @UmarAshraf: "I think i'm not explaining it correctly" -- no, you explained it perfectly fine. "The app in functionality is similar to 'vysor' it displays the home screen on the secondary display and converts the primary device into a touch pad" -- Vysor isn't an Android app. "So i need to literally display the android home screen on the secondary device" -- make your own custom ROM, or use the media projection APIs.

Comment: Hmmm... Custom ROM wont cut it for me.... i want this to be an out of the box solution. I will give Media Projection a go. I believe all the 'VYSOR' like app use the same technique where they record n play the screen. I was thinking is it possible to maybe somehow use the intent object and call the home screen in the secondary display.